How possible is it that a prokaryotic cell with hardened pili exists and that microorganisms use them as a way of hunting?
I'm creating prokaryotes for my speculative evolution project and I was wondering if it's possible for them to develop a hardened pili that would allow them to be used either as a defense or, in this case, for predation. For example, I was thinking of two prokaryotes, one spiral-shaped with a hardened pili in front and this one perforating the biofilms like a biological drill, and then another predatory cell that moves at high speed when it detects prey using its chemoreceptors, launching itself like a dart and piercing its prey and thus feeding on its remains.

Please keep in mind that our goal (per the [help/on-topic]) is to help you develop and consistently use the rules of an imaginary world of your own design. That usually means asking us to help rationalize an idea using what science might exist to support it. However, asking us to scientifically validate a fanciful idea is not what we do. Such a question might be better asked at [biology.se].

@JBH This is probably too speculative for Biology SE, and it is quite specific and answerable.

I'm sorry, I don't know what to add to explain this, since it is basically an alien world, at most I could say that the cell where it originated has pili, flagellum and a pseudopeptidoglycan wall with a PNA genetic material, I don't know what else to say

I would expect that structures such as these wouldn't be pili any more.  A pilus is a very thin, flexible tubule, whereas the OP's 'hardened pili' would need to be much thicker, and probably much shorter, since objects that would seem to look 'stiff' or 'hard' to us in our macroscopic world are in fact quite flexible at the micro or nano scale of single cells.
In general, protozoa are physically quite robust at their scale, and a 'spike' would be unlikely to affect them the way that a scaled-up spike would affect us.  At the nano-scale, the spike would either bend or the victim would be pushed aside.  In the unlikely event that it did penetrate, when the spike was withdrawn, the hole would close up.
Consider that microbiologists use micro-scale glass pipettes to penetrate single-celled prokaryotic organisms, the cells must be held in place, they deform very considerably before the pipette penetrates., and when the pipette is withdrawn, the organism doesn't spill its contents everywhere.
ICSI footage from Fertility Associates
So, for a single-celled organism to penetrate and thus feed upon another cell, it would need something other than an inert spike.  The modified pilus would need to be tipped with some means of penetrating the cell membrane, and would also need some way of 'digesting' the prey cell's contents so that it didn't end up hybridising with it, since pili are used in bacterial conjugation.
However, as long as these 'spikes' have the appropriate chemical properties, they are quite feasible.  They could be considered to be modified fimbriae.

Thanks for answering and sorry if I'm late, but anyway speaking of what you said, I have no problem using a modified hard fimbilla or pilis, the thing is that it has like a "pick" since it is something that I saw in games like Thrive (A game that tries to be as realistic as possible) and I don't know how realistic that pick is, since I want to add things that well may be probable but are not on Earth being an alien world, that is why I asked if the pili could be used as a pick and if it is possible with a fimbilla how would you do it?

@Idon'tknow While I appreciate the checkmark, it's customary to wait 24-48 hours before accepting an answer, so that other users have a chance to post something that may be even better.  Once a question has an answer, there's less incentive for users to post their own answers.

Oh sorry, well I'll wait, but in the meantime, if you have the answer on how to make a biological spike for prokaryotes, I'll wait for you

Monty It's been more than two days, what chemicals do you recommend?

@Idon'tknow The spikes would have to be tipped with some sort of enzymes to help penetrate the cell membrane, a bit like the acrosomes on spermatozoa, and it would have to inject some sort of digestive enzymes to break up the victim's contents before sucking them out.

Thank you very much
